# How to make react native sectionlist to collapse section and drag and drop items across section?

Tags: react-native, draggable, drag, react-native-sectionlist, react-native-collapsible

I am new to REACT NATIVE, I am trying to implement a sectionlist which can collapse each section and also need to drag and drop items across sections. I have tried REACT NATIVE SectionList component, but it lacks drag drop and collapse functionality.

Can you please recommend any solutions for the same. Or will I have to implement from the scratch? Help my appreciated. Sorry for not posting any code, just because I don't have any and I am looking for your thoughts in implementing the above functionality.

Comment: I kind of got one which is close to what I was looking for. Please find the link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/accordion-collapse-react-native

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following package as I have used both the package you mentioned in the comment and the following.
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible-view

With this package you can expand more than menu which is not currently available in the package you mentioned in the comment.